# bash script: search into file for value in column

Tags: bash, awk, aix

I did a search on the site but could not find something exhaustive.

I have a list of servers "hostA hostB hostc hostd" and a central host hostX

hostX connects to the servers via ssh, and obtained the following code

```
==============================================================================
----- Host Bus Adapters --------- ------ Storage System -----    - I/O Paths -
###  HW Path                         ID           Interface     Total    Dead
==============================================================================
   0 fscsi0                       CKM00130600171   CL1-06           10       0
   0 fscsi0                       CKM00130600171   CL1-02           10       0
   0 fscsi0                       CKM00130600177   CL2-06            1       1
   1 fscsi1                       CKM00130600171   CL1-03           10       0
   1 fscsi1                       CKM00130600171   CL1-07           10       0
   1 fscsi1                       CKM00130600177   CL2-07            1       1
   1 fscsi1                       CKM00130600177   CL2-03            1       1
   2 fscsi2                       CKM00130600171   CL1-06           10       0
   2 fscsi2                       CKM00130600171   CL1-02           10       0
   2 fscsi2                       CKM00130600177   CL2-02            1       1
   2 fscsi2                       CKM00130600177   CL2-06            1       1
   3 fscsi3                       CKM00130600171   CL1-03           10       0
   3 fscsi3                       CKM00130600171   CL1-07           10       0
   3 fscsi3                       CKM00130600177   CL2-07            1       1
```

I should finish a script that sees if there are dead path and sends an email allert.

but i don't know how to read the last column, I made the extrapolation of the last column but do not know how to compare

```
awk  '{print $(NF)}' /SERVER/hostA.txt  |grep -x '[0-9]*'
```

can you help me?

best regards
Isifer

Comment: Is that `grep` doing anything for you? Is your last column ever not a number?

Comment: What test do you want to apply to the last column? What do you want to do with the lines that pass/fail that test?

Comment: `awk '$NF==1{print "is dead lol"}' file` ?

Comment: if i do awk '$NF==1{print "is dead lol"}' file
he take:
count=11
==============================================================================
Dead
==============================================================================
1
1
1
1
1
1

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$NF==1' /SERVER/hostA.txt |
while IFS= read -r line
do
    mailx -s "Its dead, Jim: $line" ...
done
```

Complete/replace the mailx line as you see fit...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to grep lines that don't end in 0, you can use

```
grep '[^0]$\|[0-9]0$'
```

i.e. the last character on the line is not 0, or it's preceded by another digit.